# Node- Append file in Async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to query a database for objects and wish to write each object to a file. The console.log shows me that the data I want is being returned from the query, but the file that is created by fs.append (./returned.json) is always empty. Is it not possible to do this within an async function?

```
async function findReturned(){
    try {
        const returned = await Data.find({});
        returned.forEach(function(file) {
            returnedfiles = file.BACSDocument;
            console.log(returnedfiles);
            fs.appendFile('./returned.json', returnedfiles, 'utf-8', (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
        process.exit();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Oops...');
        console.error(e);
        process.exit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `async` function and functions with callback API
Also you can't call multiply `async` function inside `forEach`, you have to create a promise that will do what do you need in chain (see `reduce` function in example below).

Another way - to use `.map`, return an array of promises and await it using

```
await Proimse.all(arrayOfPromises)
```

but in this case the order of new data in file will not be as the order in the initial array.

In order to do that you need to promisify `fs.appendFile` and call promisified version of function

```
// add new import
const {promisify} = require('util');
// create new function with Promise API on existing Callback API function
const appendFile = promisify(fs.appendFile)

async function findReturned(){
    try {
    const returned = await Data.find({});

    // Create a single promise that will append each record one by one to the file in initial order.
    const promise = returned.reduce(function(acc, file){
        returnedfiles = file.BACSDocument;
        console.log(returnedfiles);
        acc.then(() => appendFile('./returned.json', returnedfiles, 'utf-8'));
        return acc
    }, Promise.resolve());

    // Wait until the promise resolves;
    await promise;

    process.exit();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Oops...');
        console.error(e);
        process.exit();
    }
};
```

Instead of using build int `fs` module you can use [`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) module that already has promisified versions of native methods and several extra methods.

What you can improve in your function - do not append file multiply times, but collect all data that you need to append to file into single variable and do it once.

If for some reason you have to do it multiply times - obtain file descriptor using `fs.open` and pass it instead of file name to fs.appendFile (or promisified verison). In this case do not forget co close file descriptor (`fs.Close`).

Comment: I see what you mean about not looping over an async function, however I'm still getting blank output from the file I'm trying to write to.

Comment: It should be `acc.then(() => appendFile(...))` (i.e. `appendFile` call should be wrapped inside a function)

Comment: sure, i fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use mz/fs for async function

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');

...
returned.forEach(async (file) => {
   returnedfiles = file.BACSDocument;
   await fs.writeFile('./returned.json', returnfiles, 'utf-8');
})
```

You don't need to throw the err as it will the catch.

Comment: In this case `process.exit` will close the process before the script write data to file.

Comment: I'd use simple [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead of `forEach` in order to wait before the previous file operation finishes, otherwise they might all be writing to the file at the same time.